# PHP Guzzle gives empty body stream with empty contents on forked process, how i change the uri of the stream wrapper to a custom one?

Tags: php, multiprocessing, guzzle, guzzle6

I'm working on a multi-processed task (5 childs) that at some point of code make requests to an API, takes the data, normalise and persist to database.

I'm having a problem with guzzle on this environment because sometimes i have a http 200 response but the content of the body stream comes empty and look like it because the guzzle uses by default the uri "php://temp" that seems to generate a conflict on multi-processed tasks. I tested the requests where this happens and the request works on single process. Bellow the dump of the body of response:

```
class GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream#474 (7) {
  private $stream =>
  resource(687) of type (stream)
  private $size =>
  NULL
  private $seekable =>
  bool(true)
  private $readable =>
  bool(true)
  private $writable =>
  bool(true)
  private $uri =>
  string(10) "php://temp"
  private $customMetadata =>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

There is a way to change the Guzzle Stream Wrapper to a custom one to avoid conflicts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was my mistake, once we read the body stream if we need to reuse we need to rewind the stream to read it again.

I also make some changes like create a new instance on each child instead of use the copy of guzzle client from the parent.